# how to give values for jquery ui dialog attributes when we open the dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a javascript function, which is opening a jquery dialog:

```
function new_popup() {
    var editor = "victorio"; //want to give
    var sex = "male";  //want to give
    $("#new-dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 700,
        width: 800,
        modal: true,
        title: "New Dialog",
        buttons: { //.....buttons whatever.....
        },
        close: function() {
        }
    });
    $("#new-dialog-form").load('<%=newPopupUrl%>').dialog('open');
}
```

I want to give the `editor` and the `sex` values for the new dialog, which opens the "new_frame.jsp", which has two labels with the IDs:

```
<label class="form_label" id="editor"/>
<label class="form_label" id="sex"/>
```

So when we open the new dialog, these 2 labels will be auto completed with the given values.

How can I give the values for the dialog, and how and where can I get and set the given values in the new jsp? Thank you for your helping!

Comment: use the `open` callback to set the values just as you have the `close` callback in your dialog definition.

Comment: could you please give me some example, how to give the values in that open callback? thank you!

Comment: It's basic jQuery... so something like `open : function() { $('#editor').html(editor);$('#sex').html(sex); }`